# Replacement Siding; Demo Complications

Tags: construction, siding, sheathing

Location: Oklahoma City.  Tornados and storms abound.  A hail and wind storm has prompted the replacement of the vinyl siding.  During demo of the damaged vinyl I discovered a wood siding layer underneath the vinyl.  The wood layer is rotted and in various areas the tongue and groove sheathing is exposed.  The sheathing in 30-40% of the exterior, that I have exposed from the wood siding removal, has deteriorated so much that the lightest touch turns it to powder.  Beyond the sheathing is insulation and interior sheetrock.  I feel it would be neglectful not to replace the sheathing and maybe put up an air barrier as well.  Or should i just leave the wood siding that remains and just install the vinyl siding over it.  Also the roof has just been replaced.

I'm not sure of the best way to proceed.  I was leaning towards OSB sheathing, Tyvek air barrier, foam insulation, and finally vinyl siding.

Is this the recommended course of action?

Answer (score 2):

Replacing the deteriorated siding and upgrading with the air barrier and insulation does sound like the correct route - ignoring a problem of that scale just gets more expensive to fix later.

Comment: Absolutely, while the problem areas are already open, now is the most opportune time to fix. Do not let the occasion pass.